# Where are the concrete implementations of AuthenticationManager in ASP.NET 5 source code?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm struggling on finding how ASP.NET vNext stores the user data (sesion identifier, claims, etc.) to see what kind of structures it uses to manage and persist this information.

The closer I've got is the abstract property of the AuthenticationManager class present in the Microsoft.AspNet.Http namespace, which in turn I imagine that will be overriden by a concrete class corresponding to each form of authentication (cookies, tokens, etc.), but where the hell are these concrete implementations? I've spent hours navigating it's source code and can't find this piece among the miriad of interfaces, abstraction, etc.

Could somebody cast some light here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AuthenticationManager](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/Authentication/AuthenticationManager.cs) abstract class

[DefaultAuthenticationManager](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationManager.cs) is a concrete implementation

Comment: Sorry Joe, I've written the wrong class name, I was meaning AuthenticationManager... I've edited the question.

Comment: DefaultAuthenticationManager is only a façade for a handler that is assigned somewhere as a feature of the pipeline. This is what I'm looking for, the code that really handles the SignIn in the end and stores the user credentials somewhere in memory or...

Comment: generally an encrypted cookie is used to store the claims principal, maybe what you are looking for is [SignInManager in Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/SignInManager.cs)

Comment: Identity uses the [CookieAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs)

Comment: So at the end the user claims are stored in Session... That's what I was looking for. Thanks. Please, update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the claims are stored in the cookie not in session state. Identity examples work without enabling session which is not enabled by default and only turned on by opting into session.  Whether you accept my answer is up to you. From my point of view I have answered the question that you posted and no need to update it.

Comment: Links are broken. They're [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/Authentication/AuthenticationManager.cs) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationManager.cs) now.